# How to get list of branches with number of commit Ahead from other branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

Is there a way to get list of branches with number of commit Ahead from other branch?

Consider this this branches:

```
master
feature/one
feature/two
feature/three
```

feature/* where created in same time from master. Than, in feature/one was created one new commit. In feature/two were created two new commits. In feature/three were created three new commits.

Than, feature/two was merged back to master.

I' looking for way to get this result: (number means how many commits is branch Ahead of master.

```
feature/two 0
feature/one 1
feature/three 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The script in [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38379542/1256452) should work but there's a somewhat better way, also using scripting.

The first thing to realize is that there is no need to check out each branch.  All we want is a count of commits that are "on" (contained within) the given branch that are not also on (contained within) `master`, and the `master..$branch` syntax will suffice to specify those.

Using `git log --online` piped to `wc -l` will work, but we can do this directly within Git using `git rev-list --count`.

Last, `git branch` is a so-called "porcelain" Git command, vs Git's "plumbing" commands: the plumbing commands are *designed* for scripting while the porcelain ones are not.  Usually scripts work better with the plumbing commands.  The way to get a list of branches with a plumbing command is slightly verbose:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

Putting these together we get:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/head |
    while read branch; do
        printf "%s " $branch  # %s just in case $branch contains a %
        git rev-list --count master..$branch
    done
```

which is really basically the same thing, just using plumbing commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of commits in the log:

```
#! /bin/bash
git branch \
| while read b ; do
    b=${b#\* }                          # Remove the current branch mark.
    git checkout "$b" &>/dev/null
    printf "$b "
    git log --oneline master..@ | wc -l
done
```

Comment: can you please a bit clarify how to run it? On Windows?

Comment: On Windows? Install cygwin (I'm not sure git-bash is enough) or run linux in MSWin, they say it's possible now.

Comment: ok, so this is .sh script? (sorry for ignorace, but I never used linux..)

Comment: @Chatumbabub: Yes, it's a bash script.